# How can i find specific char in file with file_pointer?

Tags: c, file-pointer

I want to make simple login,register system. and register part is done, but login part is little confuse..

Login with Txt file. Filename - ID, file including "Nickname|PW"

then scanf ID first, if id exist -> get PW and open ID txt file to compare pw.

I'm tried fgets and fread and more... but i dont know exactly how to use them

```
int ckk; // position of "|"

ck_pw = fopen(fpp_id, "r"); //open ID txt file to read including text

for (int j = 0;; j++) { // count where is "|"
    char buf; // buffer
    buf = '\0'; //reset buf
    fread(buf, j, 1, ck_pw);
    if (buf == '|') { //find "|"
        ckk = j + 1;
        break;
    }
}

fseek(ck_pw, ckk, SEEK_CUR); //move cursor to "|"

for (int k = 0;; k++) { //read text before space(NULL)
    fread(pw_ck, k, 1, ck_pw);
    if (pw_ck[k] == NULL) {
        break;
    }
}
```

I used an uninitialized "ck_pw" local variable. 
in Visual studio 2017

Comment: You should check `fread` return value.

Comment: So is the code itself correct?

Comment: Yes? No? Define "correct". `for (int j = 0;; j++)` and `for (int k = 0;; k++)` are endless loops, in case there is no `|` in the file, `pw_ck[k] == NULL` - you are comparing `char` with a `void*` (assuming `pw_ck` is some `char[?]` pointer and is valid), the code is incomplete (`main` is missing and relevant `#include`s, also the declarations of `ck_pw`, `fpp_id`, `pw_ck` etc. is missing), you don't check the return value of `fread` nor of `fopen` nor of `fseek`. The second loop doesn't make any sense, you are reading `k` characters and increment k endlessly, the code will not work as intended

Comment: There are many existing posts on this site about reading lines from text files using C. Have you read any of those to see if they solve your problem?